# Bypass reCAPTCHA using cloudscraper / cfscrape / sellenium in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, recaptcha

I am scraping a website and got stuck on the reCAPTCHA. I saw some solutions with cloudscraper, but they all involve paid services from 3rd tier websites.
T noticed this solution [nonoCAPTCHA](https://github.com/mikeyy/nonoCAPTCHA) and also that it may be possible using sellenium, but have no idea how to integrate it to this code

```
url = 'https://patrickhlauke.github.io/recaptcha'
headers = {
            'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; SunOS sun4m; en-US; rv:1.4b) Gecko/20030517 Mozilla Firebird/0.6",
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
            'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7',
            'Referer': 'http://www.google.com/?q=' + randomString(random.randint(5,10)),
            'Keep-Alive': str(random.randint(110,120)),
            'Connection': 'keep-alive'
            }
session = cloudscraper.create_scraper(
      interpreter='nodejs', recaptcha={'provider': 'return_response'}
)
session.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Or if you have any other idea to bypass this [reCAPTCHA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZE5f.png), I would appreciate

Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code you're working on and if you provided more details on what you've tried so far. Mind updating your question with that info?

Comment: I've updated it, I haven't tried much except switching from cfscrape to cloudscraper cause cfscrape hanged on forever while cloudscraper works fine for cloudlfare protected website, but now i'm stuck with the reCAPTCHA challenge.